# One figure at the top of each column in twocolumn article

Tags: floats, two-column

I have a two-column article with many figures, which work out to a little less than 1 figure per column over all pages.  In the text, some of the figures are mentioned in bunches, so that a naive placement ends up having pages with any number of figures in each column.

**Is it possible to constrain the layout such that at most one figure is allowed at the top of each column?**

I do not care where a given figure ends up being placed.

I am currently distributing the figures by hand, but that is very fragile.  In fact, I already need to maintain two placement schemes for slightly different typesetting.

I cannot put two figures each in a full-width minipage, since graphics and captions can have ungainly differences in height.

Comment: Please add a minimal working example to your question so users can reproduce your problem.

Comment: `\setcounter{topnum}{1}`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Perfect, thank you. The combination of `\setcounter{topnumber}{1}`, `\setcounter{bottomnumber}{0}`, and `\setcounter{totalnumber}{1}` has fixed my problem right away. I get some warnings that floats are stuck, but I cannot see any negative effect from that. 

Care to write up an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: Or just use `\begin{figure}[t]`.  BTW, `totalnumber` has more to do with [h] floats.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set

```
\setcounter{topnumber}{1}
```

Only one float will appear at the top of a column.

You can set the other values to 0 such as

```
\setcounter{bottomnumber}{0}
```

or set `\def\fps@figure{t}`so only top floats are considered for `\begin{figure}` unless other areas added by the optional argument such as `[p]`

Comment: Thanks to this answer, I found [this great other answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/39020/283189), which also points out `dbltopnumber` among other useful things.

Comment: oh yes Frank's opus, but referencing that is more like "read the manual" than answering a specific question (source2e.pdf also has this information in principle of course)